# Adding new range of numbers as column in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

i wanted to add a new column as a Kind of number to indicate the values to my dataframe created in Pandas.

```py
train = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Messungen\TDXD1000A_Engine-Off.csv", sep=';')

seq = range(len(train.columns))

for x in seq:
    print(x)
train.insert(0, 'measurement_index', x)
print(train)
```

```
Output:
[            measurement_index     t[s] timeslices[5].profilerDataProcess[8]_C0[us]  \
0                    351         3,9610                                      0,0000   
1                    351         3,9620                                      0,0000   
2                    351         3,9630                                      0,0000   
3                    351         3,9640                                      0,0000   
4                    351         3,9650                                      0,0000   
...                  ...      ...                                         ...   
59843                351        63,9570                                      0,0000   
59844                351        63,9580                                      0,0000   
59845                351        63,9590                                      0,0000   
59846                351        63,9600                                      0,0000   
59847                351        63,9610                                      0,0000
```

why am i not gettin the range of numbers from 0 to 351 in my new column? I get only 351 as all the values of my column?

Comment: In your code `train.insert...` should be within the `for` loop scope. you are using it out of `for` loop. by the way easy to do direct `>>> train['measurement_index'] = seq`

Comment: Format your code correctly. Use backticks or tabs or four spaces to put it in code format. Use more spaces to maintain indentation.

Comment: It does not work even when i use train.insert inside for loop it throws an error like this: (ValueError: cannot insert measurement_index, already exists) . And when using your code i get this:(ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your existing code, you are getting constant values as 351 because the `train.insert(0, 'measurement_index', x)` statement is present outside the `for` loop.

You can add the new column as simple as this. No need to use for loops and make it complex

```
seq = list(range(len(train.columns) + 1)). # The +1 is because the end value of range is usually one value less

train['measurement_index'] = seq  # Just assign the generated range to a new dataframe column
```

Comment: It does not work even when i use train.insert inside for loop it throws an error like this:  (ValueError: cannot insert measurement_index, already exists) . And when using your code  i get this:(ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index )

Comment: Can you try checking if the length of "seq" and the length of the "train" dataframe is same?